# How to show DIV only after receiving reply message from server?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jsf

I want to show a particular DIV only after i get the response from my server.

What I am trying to do is, a password recovery function for my users. I get their registered email ID, and then I checked it with my database. If it is present in my database, I send a message back inside a div, stating the password has been sent to your mail ID. If it is an un-registered email ID, I send a different message stating email id not registered.

Here are my two divs:

DIV To get my users email ID

```
<div  id="fgpass" >
                  
                    <div id="newpass">
                        <div style="position: absolute;top: 10%;left: 10%;">
                            <center><h2>PASSWORD RECOVERY</h2></center>
                            <h4> Enter Your Registered</h4> 
                        
                      
                  <h4>E-Mail Address :</h4>
                        
                    <f:view>
                        <h:form>
                         <center>
                             <h:inputText id="cmailid" required="true" value="#{forgotPass.mailid}"/>
                             <h:commandButton value="Submit"   action="#{forgotPass.fpass}">

                            </h:commandButton>
                            
                           
                    
                         </center>
                   
                   </div>
                    </div>
                             
                            </h:form>
                </div>
                          
            </div>
```

DIV to show the server response message

```
  <div id="msg" onclick="$('#msg').hide();">
            <div style="position: absolute;top: 20%;left: 2%;">
                   <span style="font-size: medium;">
                         <h:outputLabel  value="#{forgotPass.finalresult}"/>
                   </span>
            </div>
    </div>
```

My CSS

```
#fgpass {
    position: absolute;
    left: 65%;
    top: 4%;
    
    border-color: #009900;
    border-width: 3px;
    border-radius: inherit;
   z-index: 800;
   
}
#newpass{
   position: absolute;
   z-index: 1000;
   height:160px;
   width: 250px;
  color: midnightblue;
  
   visibility: hidden;
   background-color: lavender;
   -moz-border-radius: 8px;
   border-radius: 8px;
   border-width: 3px;
   border-color:#444;
}  
#msg {
    z-index: 5000;
   width:160px;
   height: 150px;
    -moz-border-radius: 8px;
   border-radius: 8px;
   border-width: 3px;
   border-color:#444;
    position: absolute;
    left: 85%;
    top:3%;
    cursor: pointer;
   background-color: navajowhite;
    
}
```

My problem is that the msg DIV is always visible on the screen whenever page loads or reloads. I want it to be visible only if it gets the response from my server . Is there any JQUERY or JAVASCRIPT or simple CSS method to do this?

Comment: Which jsf version are you using? if its version 2 or above, use the inbuilt ajax framework. otherwise you could use ajax4jsf. using jquery to send ajax request will be a bad idea.

Comment: @johny i am using jsf and getting the result by accessing a class forgotPass.finalresult and then trying to display the same in a div ....

Answer (score 1):

When the page loads you need to hide the div. Adding an extra style to `#msg` will do that

```
#msg
{
    display: none;
}
```

If you are using AAJAX to get the response from the server then you can use the below code

```
$("#msg").show();
```

inside the **success callback** function for the ajax request. [jQuery AJAX](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

Answer (score 1):

Using jquery function you could

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#msg").hide();

    // later after ajax?

    $.ajax(url).success (function(data) {
      $("#msg").show();
      return false;
    });
});
```

Answer (score -1):

```
<form method='post' action='#'>
    <input type='text' name='email' placeholder="person@example.com">
    <input type='submit' name="send" value='submit'>
</form>
<?php 
//connect you database here
//after user submits the email check if the email exits

$sql = 'select * from yourtable where email='.$_POST['email'];
$res = mysql_query($sql);
if(mysql_count_rows($res)==1){
  ?>
  <script>
        var unhide_div = document.getElementById('mydiv');
        unhide_div.style.visibility = 'visible';

  </script>

  <?php 

  }else{
      die('Email verification failed!!!');
      }
?>
```

If the email is checked your message is shown here!!